# Error for loop initial declaration are only allowed in c99

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out how to implement a for loop in c89 for an assignment but was using a different compiler online before going to the command prompt. When compiling  "Error for loop initial declaration are only allowed in c99 or c11 mode"  any suggestions on how to correct this?

```
void drawLine(int N, char C) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", C);
    }
}

void drawSquare(int N, char C) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%c", C);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an academic exercise to use C89, or some kind of punishment being inflicted upon you?

Comment: @tadman For students to become cognisant of "scoping" can hardly be considered particular punishment. There's enough SO questions raised by beginners not understanding scoping, even when they're using the most up-to-date compiler.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I'm asking about the requirement to use C89, not about scoping.

Comment: @tadman Excuse me for reading beyond the comma of your question.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I wouldn't call being forced to use C89 anything but in this day and age.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring variables inside the first part of a `for` statement is something that was added to the C99 standard.  If your code needs to conform to C89, then move the declaration before the loop.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%c\n", C);
}
```

Comment: For the OP, bear in mind the semantic change in doing this. The scope of the variable `i` is no longer limited to the loop if it's declared outside of the loop.

Comment: Thank you, also can it be the same variable for each function or does it need to be different for each function?

Comment: @clpoland It depend on where you declare the variable.  If it's declared outside of any function, any function defined after it can access it.  If it's declared inside of a function, it can only be used in the scope in which it was declared.

Comment: @clpoland If you want to limit the scope of, for instance, `int i;` in this case, simply nest what's been shown here inside another pair of curly braces (to form a block.) (Include a comment, too.)